# Keeping DialogFragment in backstack after navigation to another Fragment in Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Jetpack Navigation for dialogs in the app. Basically, I am navigating to another fragment from my DialogFragment with generated action methods. However, when I press back button or call findNavController().popBackStack() in the navigated Fragment, it does not navigate back to the DialogFragment, instead I am taken back to the original Fragment from which the DialogFragment was opened. Is there a way to keep DialogFragment in the back stack without any workarounds such as showing the dialog again manually as soon as I navigate back.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem，using the following code，I can call findNavController().popBackStack() in the navigated Fragment,but I can't back to the original Fragment(Activity) from which the DialogFragment was opened.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener { dialog, keyCode, event ->
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
      this.binding.navHost.findNavController().navigateUp()
      return@setOnKeyListener true
    }else{
      return@setOnKeyListener false
    }
  }
```